# Gravity Forms - Dynamically populate a drop down based on entries from another gravity form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

So I am looking at dynamically populating a drop down field in a form with entries from another gravity form. Based on that choice, I will populate a second drop down dynamically based on entries from a gravity form.

More or less I am creating the ability to submit a work order. In that work order I want users to select a piece of equipment then based on that piece of equipment they can select a part.

I have looked at gform_get_entries_args_entry_list as a way of snagging entries, but I am not overly sure how to set it so it pulls from a particular form.

add_filter( 'gform_get_entries_args_entry_list', 'machine' );
function populate_posts( $form ) {

```
foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

    $items = gform_get_entries_args_entry_list( 'NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE' );

    $choices = array();

    foreach ( $items as $GRAVITY FORM ENTRY VARIABLE) {
        $choices[] = array( 'text' => $GFEV->THE MACHINE NAME, 'value' => $GFEV ->The Name Field of the machine );
    }

    $field->placeholder = 'Select a Post';
    $field->choices = $choices;

}

return $form;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The [Gravity Forms Dynamic Population Pro plugin](https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-dynamic-population/) uses the `GFAPI:get_entries` function, which you can just directly pass the form ID.

Here's the definition:

`public static function get_entries( $form_ids, $search_criteria = array(), $sorting = null, $paging = null, &$total_count = null )`

Comment: I searched and searched and yet never found this! Thanks!